Scraping data from public google sheet directly without API
I have a Chrome extension that fetches and displays data from a publicly published Google Sheet (published to the web, not via the Google Sheets API). The extension does not have its database, so it scrapes the data directly from the sheet and updates it periodically (currently set at 1 hour).
I’m concerned about potential issues as my user base grows. Specifically, I’d like to know:

Does Google implement rate limits or restrictions for large-scale access to a publicly published Google Sheet?
If I have many users, each scraping the sheet periodically (e.g., every hour), could this trigger rate limits or access issues?

Thanks in advance
Currently I am expecting to know what issues I may face when my userbase grow
